# How to extract data from text input from flat list and send to array react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following problem:
I am displaying data from an API in a FlatList and it contains a text input for each element, what I need is to know how to store each data entered in those text inputs and store them in an array.

I tried to do it and when I fill a text input the array is filled, everything fine at that point, but when I fill another text input the previous value is replaced by the new one.

I hope you can help me

my array code

```
const [tareas, setTareas] = useState([]);
var T_array = [];
  const inputHandler = (text, id) => {
    T_array.push({cantidad:text, id: id})
    setTareas(T_array);
    console.log(T_array);
  };
```

My Flat List

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0.7 }}>
        <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          //scrollEnabled={false}
          data={tareas_data}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
              <View style={styles.genContainer}>
                <Text style={styles}>Descripción: {item.accion} de</Text>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles}>
                    {item.quantity} {item.item}
                  </Text>

                  <Text style={styles.group}>Se Realiza {item.accion} de </Text>
                  <TextInput
                    containerStyle=""
                    style={styles.inputNumber}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    defaultValue="0"
                    maxLength={2}
                    key={index}
                    onChangeText={(text) => inputHandler(text, item.id)}
                  ></TextInput>
                  <Text style={styles}>{item.item}</Text>
                  
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

TextInput is inside the RenderComponent function, and it is inside Coba, which means that in every rendering, a new RenderComponent function is created, and the old RenderComponent function is thus unmounted.

To solve the problem, create RenderComponent function outside of Coba, and pass all necessary

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';

```
const RenderComponent = (props) => {
    return (<TextInput
    key={props.index}
        style={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'orange'}}
        value={props.data[props.index].name}
        onChangeText={val => {
            let newArray = [...props.data];
            newArray[props.index].name = val
            props.setData(newArray);
            console.log(props.data); //always rerender when type one character.. please help!!
        }}
    />);
}

function Coba() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {id: 1, name: "dono"},
        {id: 2, name: "kasino"},
        {id: 3, name: "indro"}
    ]);

    const renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
            <Text>name {item.id}</Text>
            <RenderComponent item={item} index={index} data={data} setData={setData} />
        </View>
    );

    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 50}}>
        
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />

        </View>
    );
}`

> `enter code here`

`
```